# .Net Aspose.Words reading from word document

Tags: c#, .net, excel, file-io, aspose.words

I use Aspose to write to a word file and read and write to an excel file. I am trying to get Aspose.Words to read from a Word document but I keep getting error messages. I have followed examples from Aspose.com and those aren't useful. I posted on the forum and I still haven't heard back from them.

I am wanting to read these field codes (example: `{fillin "Date" \d ""}`) from each word document, which there are multiples of them. Once I am able to get those extracted, I want to put those in a `List<string>` and verify that they aren't duplicates. After I have gone through all the documents, I need to print that list into an excel spreadsheet.

Can someone help me resolve this error issues or tell me an easier way to go about this?

Issue #1 - won't recognize the file.

```
//string path = @"C:\Users\kbangert\Desktop\Karpel\HonoluluHIChargeCode2\Charge Language\10C104X.doc";
//string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"] + "10C104X.doc";
//Document doc = new Document(path);
//Document doc = new Document(file);
Document doc = new Document(@"10C104.docx");
```

I have tried different techniques and I get the same errors - "UnsupportedFileFormatException was unhandled" or "FileCorreptionException was unhandled". I know the files are fine so is it the field codes that are causing this issue?

Issue #2 - Cannot resolve symbol 'Fields' or 'FieldCollection'

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
FieldCollection fields = doc.Range.Fields;
foreach (Field field in fields)
    sb.AppendLine(field.GetFieldCode());
```

This came from the developers at Aspose and this throws the above errors.

Comment: Katherine, please provide the Aspose forum link where you posted your original issue. I'll follow up with the respective team to get a clear idea of the situation or the fix. Sometimes the issue might occur due to particular file structure or contents etc., but we can try to provide you a fix for that. You can also try with the latest version; it might have been fixed already in some previous version. Please note that I'm responsible to manage technical support at Aspose. I'll try my best to help you with this issue.

Comment: @ShahzadLatif - here is the link. I did hear back from someone. I am still trying to get this to work. http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/508091/508091/showthread.aspx#508091

Answer (score 0):

For issue #1, there is no telling exactly why the file is failing, so you would need to get Aspose involved in that. However, we use the the following Aspose method to determine whether or not Aspose will be able to open the file:

```
Aspose.Words.FileFormatUtil.DetectFileFormat(fileName).LoadFormat
```

You should also double check to see if the file exists where your app expects it to exist before trying to open it using System.IO.File.Exists.

For issue #2 you need to add the namespace for the fields to the top of your class:

```
using Aspose.Words.Fields;
```

In addition, it looks like the developers may have provided information different than the version you are working with. In our code, the reference is to `doc.Range.FormFields` and the collection type is `FormFieldCollection`. I am not sure what the `GetFieldCode` equivalent is.

Comment: For issue #2, I have that in the using statements.

Comment: @Katherine: I have updated the answer revised information for issue #2.

Comment: The field codes aren't in a form, so I'm not sure that is going to work.